# Monitor emits a faint noise when certain patterns are displayed

Tags: display, lcd

Under normal circumstances, the Dell E2310Hc LCD Monitor seems to work fine.  However, when I display an large array of hash characters ("#") a faint buzz can be heard from the monitor.  It appears to be correlated to the periodic pattern somehow:

- Increasing the size of the pattern (i.e. changing the font size) changes the frequency of the noise.
- Adding more pattern enhances the sound.
- Increasing the contrast increases the intensity of the sound.
- Color does not seem to affect the sound.
- Increasing the contrast of the pattern w.r.t. the background increases the sound.
- **Edit**: Horizontally tiled patterns make little contribution, but vertically tiled patterns cause the majority of the noise.

What could be causing this?  I also noticed the same issue with another LCD monitor but it's a lot less perceptible.

Comment: Have you verified this happens with somebody else present?

Comment: No I have not done so.

Comment: Are we troubleshooting for electrokenesis by having the other person present?  Also, what if their hearing isn't as good as @fyl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electromagnetic forces generated by the flows of electricity within the device are causing parts to vibrate due to alternating magnetic attraction and repulsion.

Comment: Is this normal behavior for a "typical LCD monitor" though?

Comment: It's normal behavior for absolutely every single electric or electronic device on the planet.