# High pitch noise when monitor displays anything in table form

Tags: windows-8.1, display, noise

I've come across a lot of posts handling noises of batteries, computers, chargers,... but what I'm experiencing, I've never seen before.

I'm working on a LG Ultrawide monitor 29UM65 (ratio 21:9). Whenever I display anything with lines on a regular distance (f.e. excel, other table-based applications or webpages), my monitor starts making a high pitch noise. It's very noticable for me, but the majority of the people in the office don't notice this.

What I'm curious about is what could be the cause of this, technically? It's as if the refresh rate of the monitor could make a difference, although I haven't found how to change that for this one (probably not possible at all).

Any ideas what could be causing this behavior and if there's something that could be done to resolve it?

Comment: Have you checked answer to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/464603/monitor-emits-a-faint-noise-when-certain-patterns-are-displayed

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Haven't stumbled across that one and this is indeed related. But the tests he/she describes, don't match what I'm experiencing.

Comment: is this same as described over here ?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gc0tJjJsts

Comment: do you have the same issue if also you enter a lot of # characters?

Comment: @MátéJuhász: No, it seems I don't. Horizontal lines seem to be the worst.